# How do I pass get parameters in a post/put simple_form with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

With simple_form 2.0.4, I do:

```
= simple_form_for(@thing) do |f|
```

It generates:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/things/37" class="simple_form" id="edit_thing_37" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

But I need:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/things/37?foo=bar" class="simple_form" id="edit_thing_37" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

How to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could write

```
= simple_form_for(@thing, :url => thing_path(@thing, :foo => 'bar')) do |f|
```